# Field `mobile_number` does not exist (odoo12)

Tags: python, odoo

I would like to create a registration module for odoo with a mobile number but I encountered the following error:

```
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1108, in _validate_fields
    check(self)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 351, in _check_xml
    self.postprocess_and_fields(view.model, view_doc, view.id)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 1111, in postprocess_and_fields
    self.raise_view_error(message, view_id)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 548, in raise_view_error
    raise ValueError(message)
ValueError: Field `mobile_number` does not exist

Error context:
View `view.users.form.inherit`
[view_id: 859, xml_id: tg_signup_mobile.view_users_form_inherit, model: res.users, parent_id: 144]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 663, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3841, in _load_records
    data['record']._load_records_write(data['values'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3779, in _load_records_write
    self.write(values)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 444, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3350, in write
    fields[0].determine_inverse(records)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1125, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 275, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 444, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3324, in write
    self._write(store_vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3460, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1112, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.exceptions.ValidationError: ('Error while validating constraint\n\nField `mobile_number` does not exist\n\nError context:\nView `view.users.form.inherit`\n[view_id: 859, xml_id: tg_signup_mobile.view_users_form_inherit, model: res.users, parent_id: 144]', None)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 656, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 314, in _handle_exception
    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 87, in reraise
    raise value
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 698, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 346, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\service\model.py", line 97, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 339, in checked_call
    result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 941, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\http.py", line 519, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 966, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\web\controllers\main.py", line 954, in _call_kw
    return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 759, in call_kw
    return _call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\api.py", line 746, in _call_kw_multi
    result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "<decorator-gen-67>", line 2, in button_immediate_upgrade
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 74, in check_and_log
    return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 622, in button_immediate_upgrade
    return self._button_immediate_function(type(self).button_upgrade)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_module.py", line 561, in _button_immediate_function
    modules.registry.Registry.new(self._cr.dbname, update_module=True)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\registry.py", line 86, in new
    odoo.modules.load_modules(registry._db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 417, in load_modules
    force, status, report, loaded_modules, update_module, models_to_check)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 313, in load_marked_modules
    perform_checks=perform_checks, models_to_check=models_to_check
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 222, in load_module_graph
    load_data(cr, idref, mode, kind='data', package=package, report=report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\modules\loading.py", line 68, in load_data
    tools.convert_file(cr, package.name, filename, idref, mode, noupdate, kind, report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 802, in convert_file
    convert_xml_import(cr, module, fp, idref, mode, noupdate, report)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 865, in convert_xml_import
    obj.parse(doc.getroot(), mode=mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 755, in parse
    self.parse(rec, mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 764, in parse
    exc_info[2]
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\pycompat.py", line 86, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 758, in parse
    self._tags[rec.tag](rec, de, mode=mode)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\tools\convert.py", line 663, in _tag_record
    record = model.with_context(rec_context)._load_records([data], self.mode == 'update')
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3841, in _load_records
    data['record']._load_records_write(data['values'])
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3779, in _load_records_write
    self.write(values)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 444, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3350, in write
    fields[0].determine_inverse(records)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\fields.py", line 1125, in determine_inverse
    getattr(records, self.inverse)()
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 275, in _inverse_arch
    view.write(data)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\odoo 12.0\server\odoo\addons\base\models\ir_ui_view.py", line 444, in write
    return super(View, self).write(self._compute_defaults(vals))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3324, in write
    self._write(store_vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 3460, in _write
    self._validate_fields(vals)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Odoo 12.0\server\odoo\models.py", line 1112, in _validate_fields
    raise ValidationError("%s\n\n%s" % (_("Error while validating constraint"), tools.ustr(e)))
odoo.tools.convert.ParseError: "Error while validating constraint

Field `mobile_number` does not exist

Error context:
View `view.users.form.inherit`
[view_id: 859, xml_id: tg_signup_mobile.view_users_form_inherit, model: res.users, parent_id: 144]
None" while parsing file:/c:/program%20files%20(x86)/odoo%2012.0/server/local_addons/tg_signup_mobile/views/view_users_form.xml:4, near
<record id="view_users_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">view.users.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">res.users</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//h2/field[@name='login']" position="after">
                    <h2><field name="mobile_number"/></h2>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
```

my model:

```py
from re import search
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class ResUsers(models.Model):
    _inherit = "res.users"
    mobile_number = fields.Char(string="شماره موبایل", required=True, size=11)

    @api.constrains("mobile_number")
    def check_validation(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.mobile_number:
                if not search("^(\+98|0)?9\d{9}$", record.mobile_number):
                    raise ValidationError("شماره موبایل وارد شده نامعتبر است.")
```

my view:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
         <record id="view_users_form_inherit" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">view.users.form.inherit</field>
            <field name="model">res.users</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="base.view_users_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//h2/field[@name='login']" position="after">
                    <h2><field name="mobile_number"/></h2>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

I'm depended the base module in manifast. I'm running in odoo 12.

What is the cause of the error I'm getting?

Comment: Just make sure you imported the module in your `__init__.py` Odoo require that you import the modules that you want to add their changes to database. Because your code looks fine and the field should be added to model.

Comment: this way not working. thanks

Comment: I think odoo doesn't even run my module python files because when I even falsely wrote outside of the python framework like that in the file and it definitely should have given me python error and not like the xml files first Checks because I completely removed xpath from the xml file but still didn't check the python files. Thank you in advance

Comment: Your code looks fine to me check your configuration, and remember to import the package that contains your py files in the addon init file too.

Comment: im added py file in init.

Comment: im uploaded module in google drive. https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XvSBfLFcSftR36H4XOuzIUt4fWoqnVRJ

Comment: I don't know if this will work like that, but you should put you model definition in a separate file then import it in your init file, you could see how this is done in odoo default module. But really I don't know what you are doing wrong just google it.

Comment: I've done that and made a separate folder called ```models```, and then put ```__init__```and it didn't work again. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem myself. I had to include the base_setup module in addition to the base module.